# Add Spinning progress for ImageView in Android

Tags: android, imageview, progress-bar, android-volley, image-load

I have an ImageView in which i want to show **ProgressBar** while loading the image from **URL**. To load image i am using **VolleyPlus** library. Here is the code to load image:

```
DiskLruBasedCache.ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new DiskLruBasedCache.ImageCacheParams(getApplicationContext(), "CacheDirectory");
cacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(0.5f);
SimpleImageLoader mImageFetcher = new SimpleImageLoader(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.progress, cacheParams);
mImageFetcher.get(image_url, imgView);
```

Now my problem is **Can i make drawable to make ProgressBar** (R.drawable.progress) **within ImageView**.

Comment: There are often options in the library to achieve that functionality, i use image loader library and it does have that option

Comment: @SarthakMittal is there any way to solve for my existing problem ?

Comment: the problem is that i haven't used that library, is there any documentation of your library or something, that might be of some help

Comment: Volley is nice library but it doesn't have enough doc

Comment: you can also search all the methods present in your library and maybe you will find the one you need

Answer (score 0):

You use *setDefaultImageResId* to an image to show during loading and if failed but you will not be able to use a view though. You can however use FrameLayout and ProgressBar behind NetworkImageView to show spinning progress while loading.

In case of successful download you do not have to do anything thing because Android should draw the progress view because it is hidden, in case of failure you will have to take it off.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>
```